# Удаление option по условию в select

Tags: javascript

Есть тег `<select>` с вложенными `<option>`:

```html
<select class="select" id="users-list" name="user">
    <option value="selected" disabled="" selected="">Select user</option>
    <option value="1">Leanne Graham</option>
    <option value="2">Ervin Howell</option>
    <option value="3">Clementine Bauch</option>
    <option value="4">Patricia Lebsack</option> 
</select>
```

Как обойти `<select>` и удалить все `<option>` кроме `<option>` с `value="selected"`?

Написал такую функцию:

```js
function clearUserSelect() {
    for (let i = userSelect.options.length; i >= 1; i--) {
        userSelect.remove(i);
    }
}
```

В принципе все работает, но хотелось бы более универсальную функцию типа:

```js
function clearUserSelect() {
    for (let i of userSelect) {
        if (i.value !== 'selected') {
            i.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

В данном случае не срабатывает строка `i.remove();`

Что исправить чтоб заработало?

Comment: *"В данном случае нее срабатывает строка i.remove();"* --- потому что `selected` - это не `value`, а атрибут

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А зачем париться, если можно:

```js
document.querySelector('#users-list').innerHTML = '<option value="selected" disabled="" selected="">Select user</option>';
```

```html
<select class="select" id="users-list" name="user">
        <option value="selected" disabled="" selected="">Select user</option>
        <option value="1">Leanne Graham</option>
        <option value="2">Ervin Howell</option>
        <option value="3">Clementine Bauch</option><option value="4">Patricia Lebsack</option> 
</select>
```

Но если очень хочется:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('option:not([selected])').forEach(el => {
  el.remove()
})
```

```html
<select class="select" id="users-list" name="user">
        <option value="selected" disabled="" selected="">Select user</option>
        <option value="1">Leanne Graham</option>
        <option value="2">Ervin Howell</option>
        <option value="3">Clementine Bauch</option><option value="4">Patricia Lebsack</option> 
</select>
```